# Bootstrap open modal is preventing text in input field in a sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a set up where I have a bootstrap modal which is open and it has a z-index of 1040.

Then I have a side bar which is open and it has a z-index of 9999.

You can see them stacked in the image I've provided here:

[image]

If I open my side bar while the modal is open, I cannot type into any input field in the side bar but I am able to click on links.

I've even set it up where I hide the modal backdrop but this does not solve the problem. I know that it is something with the modal because when I close the modal I can then type into the sidebar input field.

When I inspect the input field there is not any z-index set on that element.

What may going on? Thanks.

Here is my html code in the sidebar:

```
<div class="m-b">
    <a href="" class="dbSideBarClose btn btn-primary btn-block" id="dbSideBarClose">
        Close Window
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="I cannot type into this :(" value="">
</div>
<div>
    <a href="">I can click this link though...</a>
</div>
```

Here is my modal code:

```
<div class="moda inmodal" id="modalProject" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-full">Modal content goes here...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't enough information to troubleshoot your code. We don't see the full modal, or any of the custom CSS, or how you're hiding the Modal overlay.  Can you provide more detail?

Comment: This issue was tabindex="-1"... This was blocking all other input elements on the page from receiving input.